# TypeError at /liveclass/ __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class LiveClass(models.Model):
    standard = models.IntegerField()
    no_of_students_registered = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Class'

class User_details(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    standard = models.ForeignKey(LiveClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'User_details'


class Mentor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    standard = models.ManyToManyField(LiveClass)
    details = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Mentors'


class LiveClass_details(models.Model):
    standard = models.ForeignKey(LiveClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chapter_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    chapter_details = models.TextField()
    mentor_name = models.ForeignKey(Mentor, max_length=30, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class_time = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'LiveClass_details'

class LiveClass_registration(models.Model):
    class_details = models.OneToOneField(LiveClass_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.OneToOneField(User_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta: 
         verbose_name_plural = 'LiveClass_registration'
```

This is serializer for all my models, please tell a way to reduce the code in it as all of it is a repetition.

My `Serializer.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models



class LiveClass_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.LiveClass
        fields = '__all__'


class User_details_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User_details
        fields = '__all__'


class LiveClass_details_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.LiveClass_details
        fields = '__all__'

class Mentor_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Mentor
        fields = '__all__'

class LiveClass_registration_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.LiveClass_registration
        fields = '__all__'
```

My `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('liveclass/', views.List_live_class),
]
```

In `views.py` I am trying to list all the items in `Liveclass_details` column using class based `Api` view and using mixins.

My `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import mixins
from rest_framework import generics


from . import serializers
from . import models
# Create your views here.

class List_live_class(mixins.ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = models.LiveClass_details.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.LiveClass_details_serializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I don't understand the location of error and why it is occurring. I am relying on the documentation of the REST framework.

Error:

```
TypeError at /liveclass/
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/liveclass/
Django Version: 3.2.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception Location: /home/dhruv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 181, in _get_response
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/home/dhruv/Desktop/liveClassApp',
 '/home/dhruv/tutorial_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/dhruv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 17 Jun 2021 13:16:29 +0000
```

Comment: `path('liveclass/', views.List_live_class),` here `List_live_class` is a _class based view_ hence that is not how you specify a url pattern for it, you need to use the `as_view` method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `List_live_class` is a *class based view* hence if you pass it like below to `path` you will get an error:

```
path('liveclass/', views.List_live_class),
```

Instead you need to use the `as_view` method of the class and pass that in place of the view function:

```
path('liveclass/', views.List_live_class.as_view()),
```

---

> **Note**: Class names should ideally be in `PascalCase` hence you should use `ListLiveClass` instead of `List_live_class`. See [PEP 8 --
> Style Guide for Python
> Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)